# System architecture for a Real-time Dutch Auction system

Tags: javascript, php, real-time, long-polling, pusher

I am developing an app with a Dutch-style auction and a regular style auction. The web-app is in PHP and Jquery, using the [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) API for real-time interaction, since I am not yet comfortable enough in Node.js to use it directly.

**In the regular style auction, I have no real problem since each client's bid placement triggers a client-side javascript event and the client posts the bid to the server and then the server pushes that new bid price out to every client in real-time. For the Dutch, the server continuously updates the new prices to all clients without any client event, and when it is finally accepted by a client, the server reports that to all clients.**

> In a Dutch-style auction, the prices drop gradually UNTIL someone
>   accepts the bid, and if nobody accepts the bid before a preset (low) threshold
>   is reached, the price resets to its initial high value, over and over again.

I don't know the best way to broadcast the new prices from the server side, since the prices drop from time to time. The new prices are decided on the server side, and the rate of change is not necessarily regular. *One solution might be for each client browser to make continuous polls to the server to check if there is a new price, but I am not certain if it's the most effective way, or how best to do that*.

Please advice on the right way for me to do this in real-time? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could broadcast the prices with Pusher every time they are updated. If a client accepts a bid, they should send an HTTP request to the server with the price they accepted it at. When the server receives this client request, it should broadcast another event with Pusher to notify the other clients that the bid has been accepted.

Comment: **You could broadcast the prices with Pusher every time they are updated.** Thanks, I understand this, but should I set up a CRON job or something to push out the new prices? Is there a better RESTful way to schedule the broadcasts?

Comment: It depends how they are updated? Is it with a CRON job? If so, then yes, you could do it then.

Comment: Thanks Will. They are fetched from the database and updated in varying time-steps that are defined on the server-side. Will CRON be the best way to do the updates?

Comment: I would say that if you want the updates to occur asynchronously at varying time intervals, then you can use a CRON process that does this, and also broadcasts the new prices.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there might be a better way that I don't know of.